# getFullActionName() returning __ on CMS & Category Pages

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.4

Anyone noticed that if you observe the event `controller_action_predispatch` in Magento 2.4.4

```
public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
    $request = $observer->getEvent()->getRequest();
    $fullActionName = $request->getFullActionName();
    // $fullActionName gives __ value 
    // for CMS & Category pages (M2.4.4)
    // ...    
}
```

fullActionName always gives `__` (double underscores) for CMS & category pages

Bug or Feature? And how to get the correct `fullActionName`?

Also, the value is `__` for the following

- Event for `controller_front_send_response_before`
- Plugin for `Magento\Framework\App\FrontControllerInterface`::`beforeDispatch()`

**[UPDATED]**
This still gives the same `__` value for CMS & Category pages:

```
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface $action */
$action  = $observer->getEvent()->getData('controller_action');
if ($action instanceof \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward) {
    return $this;
}
$request = $observer->getEvent()->getRequest();
$fullActionName = $request->getFullActionName();
```

Comment: Confirmed the issue on CMS pages and category pages.

Comment: I might say something dumb but...won't the result always be cms_index_index for cms page ? Only the url will change but the action will be the same.

Comment: `cms_page_view` or `cms_index_index` is what's expected for CMS pages, but it's returning `___`

Comment: What is `$action` instance you have ? Maybe is it a `Redirect` one?

Answer (score 1):

For those kind of pages the event `controller_action_predispatch` called 2 times

First time for `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward` and `route`, `controller` and `action` are empty

Second time for `\Magento\Cms\Controller\Page\View` (for CMS) and `route`, `controller` and `action` are properly filled and you can use `fullActionName` method from request

You can check controller action instance in observer with following code

```php
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface $action */
$action  = $observer->getEvent()->getData('controller_action');
```

Just do nothing if $action is instance of `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward`

**[Added]**

For understand the reason you can check CMS router logic in `\Magento\Cms\Controller\Router`. The method `match` populate request and returns `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward` controller action instance for forward to correct end controller action

Comment: This is still giving the `__` value (see my updated post)